# How can you use Eloquent to find related values two tables away and in a different database?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am developing a system that extends an existing ERP system, and so is accessing two databases (both on the same MS SQL Server). I am trying to access items on the "Equipment" model (this is a table in the ERP database) through the "EquipmentInstance" model from the "EquipmentType" model (these two are in the new database). They are related as per this diagram:

[image: ER diagram depicting relationship]

The three models are as follows:

**EquipmentType**

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EquipmentType extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'dbo.EquipmentType';
    protected $connection = 'sqlsrv';
    protected $primaryKey = 'EquipmentTypeID';
    protected $fillable = [
        'TypeName',
        'ProductManager'
        ];

    public function EquipmentInstance()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(EquipmentInstance::class,'EquipmentTypeID', 'EquipmentTypeID');
    }

    public function Equipment()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Equipment::class,
            EquipmentInstance::class,
            'TypeID',
            'PartNum',
            'TypeID',
            'PartNum'
        );
    }
}
```

**EquipmentInstance**

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EquipmentInstance extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'dbo.EquipmentInstance';
    protected $primaryKey = 'EquipmentID';
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    protected $connection = 'sqlsrv';
    protected $fillable = [
        'EquipmentID',
        'EquipmentTypeID',
        'PartNum'
    ];

    public function Part()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Part::class,'PartNum','PartNum');
    }

    public function Equipment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Equipment::class,'PartNum', 'PartNum');
    }

    public function EquipmentType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(EquipmentType::class); /*,'EquipmentTypeID', 'EquipmentTypeID'*/
    }


/*    public function Attribute()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Equipment::class,'SerialNumber', 'JobNum');
    }

    public function TechNote()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Equipment::class,'SerialNumber', 'JobNum');
    }*/

}
```

**Equipment**

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Equipment extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'ERP.SerialNo';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'SerialNumber';
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    protected $connection = 'epicor';


    public function Part()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Part::class,'PartNum','PartNum');
    }

    public function Customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class,'CustNum', 'CustNum');
    }

    public function Equipment()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Equipment::class,'SerialNumber', 'JobNum');
    }

    public function EquipmentInstance()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(EquipmentInstance::class,'PartNum', 'PartNum');
    }
}
```

On the EquipmentType Controller I am trying to get all of the Equipment through the EquipmentInstance so for each EquipmentInstance I can display all of the Equipments.

**EquipmentType Controller**

```php
public function show(EquipmentType $EquipmentType)
{
    $EquipmentInstance = $EquipmentType->EquipmentInstance()
        ->get();

    $Equipments = $EquipmentType->EquipmentInstance()->Equipment()
        ->get();

    return view('EquipmentType.show', compact('EquipmentType', 'EquipmentInstance', 'Equipments'));

}
```

The error message I get is

```php
"BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::Equipment()"
```

I believe the issue is that (my understanding is rocky) that Eloquent is trying to write one query to access both databases, which is failing. However I am not sure how to proceed.

Any help would be greatly received.

Richard

**Update**

I have implemented what gbalduzzi suggested in his answer, which almost worked, and I am sure the issue is with my blade implemtention. I have nested two forloops:

```php
@foreach($EquipmentType->EquipmentInstance as $EquipmentInstance)
    @foreach($Equipments as $Equipment)
        <tr>
        <td>{{$EquipmentInstance->PartNum}} - {{$EquipmentInstance->Part->PartDescription}}</td>
         <td><a href="">{{$Equipment->SerialNumber}}</a></td>
         <td>{{$Equipment->SNStatus}}</td>
         <td>{{--{{$Equipment->Customer->LegalName}}--}}</td>
         </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Which is displaying the serial numbers (from the Equipment model) for the first EquipmentInstance only and repeating them for all EquipmentInstanced.

**Update 2**

I have proven that the issue is with first() in the suggested answer, as if I change this to last() the results change as you would expect (see update 1). So my question now is:

Is there an equivelant of first(), last() which is all() or every()?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in your database configuration, but in the way you are calling the relationship. Instead of:

```
$Equipments = $EquipmentType->EquipmentInstance()->Equipment()
    ->get();
```

use:

```
$Equipments = $EquipmentType->EquipmentInstance->first()->Equipment()
    ->get();
```

**Long answer**

In Eloquent, you can use a relationship in 2 ways:

- as a magic field (i.e. `$EquipmentType->EquipmentInstance`). In this case you get as a result an instance of the model `EquipmentInstance` (also, if you already queried it, it directly returns the value without executing a new query)
- as an eloquent query (i.e. `$EquipmentType->EquipmentInstance()`). Using it as a function, you don't get the model but a `RelationShip` instance, that is basically an eloquent query and can be chained with other eloquent methods, such as `where`, `orderBy`, ecc

So, if you call `$EquipmentType->EquipmentInstance()->Equipment()` it throws an error because the eloquent query does NOT have the relationship `Equipment()`.

On the other hand, `$EquipmentType->EquipmentInstance->Equipment` works because it calls `Equipment` on the actual model instance, that has the `Equipment` relationship properly defined.

Comment: Hi gbalduzzi - I have tried that and the error message is different, but it still does not work:

Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::Equipment does not exist.

Comment: Edited my answered, it returns a collection of objects not a single objects, so you need to ask for the first object and query the relationship on that

Comment: I have updated the question - there is still an issue with the query / blade.